# Multiple PlotLegends ignore NumberForm

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, legending

Imagine a set of curves

```
data = Transpose@Table[{Exp[t], Exp[1.1 t], Exp[1.2 t], Exp[1.3 t]},
    {t, 0, 5, 0.1}];
```

which should be labelled with numbers

```
numbers = {0.1234, 1.234, 123.4, 1234.};
legendForm = ScientificForm[#, 3] & /@ numbers
```

nicely formatted by `ScientificForm` or `EngineeringForm` or etc.. For one `PlotLegends` the output is as expected

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[#, {{Left, Top}, {Left, Top}}] &@
  LineLegend[Automatic, legendForm,
   LegendLabel -> "Legend 1", Spacings -> 0.2],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: One legend]

but for two `PlotLegends` the number format is lost:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[#, {{Left, Top}, {Left, Top}}] &@
    LineLegend[Automatic, legendForm,
     LegendLabel -> "Legend 1", Spacings -> 0.2],
   Placed[#, {{Left, Top}, {Left, Top}}] &@
    LineLegend[Automatic, legendForm,
     LegendLabel -> "Legend 2", Spacings -> 0.2]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Two legends]

Is this behaviour a bug or are the `NumberForm` functions not suitable to format `PlotLegends`? What would be an alternative method?

Comment: I thing the alternative would be to make string like this "1.23\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-1\)]\)" automatically from `ScientificForm`, which I can get from just putting quotes around numbers manually. Obvious ways like `ToString` or `TextString` doesn't work as expected, so probably it requires just another implementaion of `ScientificForm` that would produce a nice string.

Comment: @swish: Can you tell more details on how to generate the string by manually inserting quotes? For me this procedure is not working, maybe due to the Mathematica version - I use 10.3? What do you mean with "automatically from `ScientificForm`" if a **manual** quote insertion is required? Do you suggest with "another implementation of `ScientificForm`" to define a custom `ScientificForm` function or the necessity for Wolfram Research to update the built-in function?

Comment: I just tried typing `"123[ESC]*[ESC]10[CTRL-6]^-1[CTRL-SPACE]"` and the result was a string that displayed fine inside legends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `FullForm` on two cases, you will see that the first case contains:

```
List[ScientificForm[0.1234, 3], ScientificForm[1.234, 3], 
 ScientificForm[123.4, 3], ScientificForm[1234., 3]]
```

and the second one contains:

```
List[0.1234`, 1.234`, 123.4`, 1234.`]
```

I'm not sure why.
But workaround would be:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[#, {{Left, Top}, {Left, Top}}] &@
     LineLegend[Automatic, numbers, LegendLabel -> "Legend 1", 
      Spacings -> 0.2], 
    Placed[#, {{Left, Top}, {Left, Top}}] &@
     LineLegend[Automatic, numbers, LegendLabel -> "Legend 2", 
      Spacings -> 0.2]}, PlotRange -> All] /. numbers -> legendForm
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround, which requires only a minimal amount of extra work and might only fail if the exact `number` sequence appears somewhere else in the plot output - an improbable scenario.

Comment: @Choronaut you can make the substitution rule more specific so it will actually affect `LineLegend` only.